# Is every member of the community responsible for making his own eiruv tavshilin?

Tags: yom-tov, tzibur-community, motzi-yedei-chovato, shlichus-agency, eruv-tavshilin

An [eiruv tavshilin](http://www.chabad.org/holidays/passover/pesach_cdo/aid/708595/jewish/Eruv-Tavshilin.htm) is made before Yom Tov in order to allow for cooking for Shabbat on Yom Tov.

However, once I told someone I was worried I had not made my eiruv tavshilin correctly, and the person said, "We rely on the rabbi to make it" (=we don't have to make it ourselves). (This may be because we were both single women, but please ignore that consideration in answering my question.)

Is this true? What extent of shlichus/yotzeius(?) applies to eiruv tavshilin, in general? I assume only one family member per household has to make it. But could it be done, for example, by the rabbi for the whole community? When can we assume that it was done this way?

Discussed to some extent in answers here: [If you forgot to make an Eruv Tavshilin](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/3117/if-you-forgot-to-make-an-eruv-tavshilin)

Related: [Can a woman make an eiruv for her minor children?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/29115/can-a-woman-make-an-eiruv-for-her-minor-children?rq=1)

Comment: The situation with the Rbbi's eruv tavshilin is clearly answered and sourced under "2 Alternatives" at http://www.torahmusings.com/2010/10/forgotten-eruv-tavshilin/ referenced by the OP hmiself. Therefore this seems like a dup.

Answer (score 1):

I was told by a Rav of my community that we could rely on him making it for us. He said that in general this depends on the community.

Comment: Did he say this in a case where you forgot, or even from the outset?

Comment: This is a comment and the halacha is not that simple

Comment: He said if you forget but not to make a habit of it.